# DI containers leak memory or BenchmarksDotNet MemoryDiagnoser delivers inaccurate measurements?

Tags: memory-leaks, autofac, tinyioc, benchmarkdotnet

**Introduction**

We are trying to catch potential memory leaks using `BenchmarksDotNet`.

For the simplicity of example, here is an unsophisticated `TestClass`:

```
public class TestClass 
{
    private readonly string _eventName;

    public TestClass(string eventName)
    {
        _eventName = eventName;
    }

    public void TestMethod() =>
        Console.Write($@"{_eventName} ");
}
```

We are implementing benchmarking though NUnit tests in `netcoreapp2.0`:

```
[TestFixture]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class TestBenchmarks
{
    [Test]
    public void RunTestBenchmarks() =>
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<TestBenchmarks>(new BenchmarksConfig());

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestBenchmark1() =>
        CreateTestClass("Test");

    private void CreateTestClass(string eventName)
    {
        var testClass = new TestClass(eventName);
        testClass.TestMethod();
    }
}
```

The test output contains following summary:

```
         Method | Mean | Error | Allocated |
--------------- |-----:|------:|----------:|
 TestBenchmark1 |   NA |    NA |       0 B |
```

The test output also contains all the `Console.Write` output which proves that `0 B` here means no memory was leaked rather than no code was run because of compiler optimization.

**Problem**

The confusion begins when we attempt to resolve `TestClass` with `TinyIoC` container:

```
[TestFixture]
[MemoryDiagnoser]
public class TestBenchmarks
{
    private TinyIoCContainer _container;

    [GlobalSetup]
    public void SetUp() =>
        _container = TinyIoCContainer.Current;

    [Test]
    public void RunTestBenchmarks() =>
        BenchmarkRunner.Run<TestBenchmarks>(new BenchmarksConfig());

    [Benchmark]
    public void TestBenchmark1() => 
        ResolveTestClass("Test");

    private void ResolveTestClass(string eventName)
    {
        var testClass = _container.Resolve<TestClass>(
            NamedParameterOverloads.FromIDictionary(
                new Dictionary<string, object> {["eventName"] = eventName}));
        testClass.TestMethod();
    }
}
```

The summary indicates 1.07 KB was leaked.

```
         Method | Mean | Error | Allocated |
--------------- |-----:|------:|----------:|
 TestBenchmark1 |   NA |    NA |   1.07 KB |
```

`Allocated` value increases proportionally to the number of `ResolveTestClass` calls from `TestBenchmark1`, the summary for

```
[Benchmark]
public void TestBenchmark1() 
{
    ResolveTestClass("Test");
    ResolveTestClass("Test");
}
```

is

```
         Method | Mean | Error | Allocated |
--------------- |-----:|------:|----------:|
 TestBenchmark1 |   NA |    NA |   2.14 KB |
```

This indicates that either `TinyIoC` is keeping the reference to each resolved object (which does not seem to be true according to source code) or `BenchmarksDotNet` measurements include some additional memory allocations outside of method marked with `[Benchmark]` attribute.

The config used in both cases:

```
public class BenchmarksConfig : ManualConfig
{
    public BenchmarksConfig()
    {
        Add(JitOptimizationsValidator.DontFailOnError); 

        Add(DefaultConfig.Instance.GetLoggers().ToArray()); 
        Add(DefaultConfig.Instance.GetColumnProviders().ToArray()); 

        Add(Job.Default
            .WithLaunchCount(1)
            .WithTargetCount(1)
            .WithWarmupCount(1)
            .WithInvocationCount(16));

        Add(MemoryDiagnoser.Default);
    }
}
```

By the way, replacing `TinyIoC` with `Autofac` dependency injection framework didn't change the situation much.

**Questions**

Does it mean all DI framework have to implement some sort of cache for resolved objects? Does it mean `BenchmarksDotNet` is used in wrong way in a given example? Is it a good idea to hunt for memory leaks with the combination of `NUnit` and `BenchmarksDotNet` in the first place?

Answer (score 7):

I am the person who implemented MemoryDiagnoser for BenchmarkDotNet and I am very happy to answer this question.

But first I am going to describe how the MemoryDiagnoser works.

1. It gets the number of allocated memory by using available API.
2. It performs one extra iteration of benchmark runs. In your case, it's 16 (`.WithInvocationCount(16)`)
3. It gets the number of allocated memory by using available API.

`final result = (totalMemoryAfter - totalMemoryBefore) / invocationCount`

How accurate is the result? It is as accurate as the available APIs that we are using: `GC.GetAllocatedBytesForCurrentThread()` for .NET Core 1.1+ and `AppDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize` for .NET 4.6+.

The thing called GC Allocation Quantum [defines](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/Documentation/botr/garbage-collection.md#design-of-allocator) the size of allocated memory. It is usually 8k bytes.

What does it really mean: if we allocate a single object with `new object()` and GC needs to allocate memory for it (the current segment is full) it's going to allocate 8k of memory. And both APIs are going to report 8k memory allocated after a single object allocation.

```
Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize);
GC.KeepAlive(new object());
Console.WriteLine(AppDomain.MonitoringTotalAllocatedMemorySize);
```

might end up in reporting:

```
x
x + 8000
```

How BenchmarkDotNet deals with this problem? We perform a LOT of invocations (usually millions or billions), so minimize the allocation quantum size problem (it's never 8k for us).

**How to fix the problem in your case**: set the `WithInvocationCount` to a bigger number (maybe 1000).

To verify the results you might consider using some Memory Profiler. Personally I [used](http://adamsitnik.com/the-new-Memory-Diagnoser/#can-it-be-trusted-now) Visual Studio Memory Profiler which is part of Visual Studio.

Another alternative is to use [JetBrains.DotMemoryUnit](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/03/04/unit-testing-and-memory-profiling-can-they-be-combined/). It's most probably the best tool in your case.

Comment: Dear Adam, I am very happy to read an answer from `MemoryDiagnoser ` creator! Thank you very much for your work, what you are doing guys is just awesome!

Comment: I tried replacing `16` with `1024` in `BenchmarksConfig` and test output reported same numbers for  experiement with `ResolveTestClass`, but it also reported `64 B` for experiment with `CreateTestClass`. I also tried removing `Add(Job.Default .WithLaunchCount(1) .WithTargetCount(1) .WithWarmupCount(1) .WithInvocationCount(16));` line at all to let `BenchmarksDotNet` decide itself about the number of iterations and obtained same results as with `1024` invocation count: `64 B` when creating `TestClass` with `ctor` and `1.07 KB` when resolving it from container.

Comment: @foxanna then you need to verify the result with some Memory Profiler. It can be that the `1.07 KB` is true